# Trouble receiving erc20 tokens on MyEtherWallet.com

Tags: wallets, erc-20

I'm attempting to withdraw siacoin to a MyEtherWallet.com address accessed via a Trezor with 1.5 firmware.

The same address is storing a good amount of GNT.

Bittrex won't let me do the transaction because it says the destination address is invalid.

I do see that GNT is in the list on the right and SC is not. I'm not completely clear on how tokens are stored. Does it have to be in the list on the right before it will be stored? If so, is that a function of me adding it or do the developers have to add support for the coin?

Exact error: "Address: 0x22b41BCEBD969Db0dC75EA677192cD5B54436584
The address you submitted is not valid for the SC network. Cancel this withdrawal and resubmit it."

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the only compatible off-exchange wallet to store Siacoin is the Siacoin wallet.  Storage is not supported on myetherwallet.com.